# I need to take screenshots and upload to a webserver, what technology should I use?

Tags: upload, screenshot

I am building a peice of software that needs to allow a user to take a screenshot of his/her computer which will then be uploaded to a web server.

What technology should I use? I don't think js has access to the appropriate resources, but would like to keep it browser based. Help?

Comment: Want to clarify a few things. This does not need to be covert - so I am ok with prompting a user for permission. Java applet, activeX or flash maybe?

I know I can do it by writing a desktop app but would like to avoid doing so if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nope ... javascript won't work ...
you need some lib which takes a screenshot and another one which does the upload.

in .net there are builtin libs for both ([taking screenshots](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial181_Capturing-screenshots-using-Csharp.html), [upload via ftp](http://www.vcskicks.com/csharp_ftp_upload.php))

**edit:**
choose a technology which is able to create a screenshot and post it to an external resource via `POST` (or upload it via `FTP`). therefore you will need some access to local file-system ... well ... what would you think if you, as a novice, get prompted to allow access to local-filesystem (or network-resources)?

**edit2:**
as far as i know, silverlights support [taking screenshots](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/82223.aspx) ... and there would be some [ftp/post action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127981/silverlight-ftp-upload) included as well ..

Answer (score 1):

Javascript by itself cannot handle this, nor should any webpage based technology --- if a website could covertly upload files from it's visitor's computers, it would have great hacking capability.  Similarly for doing things like automatically taking a screenshot -- That's too much control for a user to give up to an unknown website.

So, any means of uploading a file will requires directly user interaction.  With that, a simple HTML form with a `<input type="file" />` element should be all that is needed.