# Upload file to ftp in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

Im new to silverlight and i want the procedure of how to upload file on ftp in silverlight 4 application, Im using C#. So far i know that there are two procedure of doing this one is web client object and other is HttpWebRequest but i want to know if it is possible to upload a file to ftp server and how to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Silverlight Ftp Upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127981/silverlight-ftp-upload)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FTP is not supported in Silverlight however you could try to upload via http.

Check:
[Silverlight Ftp Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127981/silverlight-ftp-upload)

Answer (score 0):

Ftp is now possible with Silverlight 5, as the port-range got a boost (by `ClientAccessPolicy.xml`) and an elevated-trust in-browser mode is available.

I've created [sharpLightFtp](https://github.com/dittodhole/sharpLightFtp) to enable rudimental Ftp.